# How can I copy files and rename them according to their origin directories using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows

I have many directories with generically named txt files inside.  I want to make copies of the txt files, rename them according to the containing directory of each, then move them to the parent directory (that being the directory that holds the directories that hold the original txt files, designated "txts" in the script below).  I want to retain the original txt files with their original names in their original directories as well so that nothing within the original directories changes.

I have an old script that I think achieved (some of) my goals once, perhaps moving instead of copying the original txt files, but I'm unable to run it successfully now:

```
require 'find'
require 'fileutils'

Find.find("txts") do |path|
  if FileTest.directory?(path)
    next
  end

  ret = path.scan(/.*txts\/([^\/]+)\/.*/)
  name = ret[0].to_s + ".txt"
  FileUtils.mv(path, name)
end
```

Years ago a friend wrote this and ran it from within a unix environment with success.  When I run it now, an enormous number of errors are returned.  I'm using Ruby 2.2.2 and it's entirely possible there's a placeholder somewhere that I'm too newbish to recognize, or perhaps something changed from the older version of FileUtils...  I truly have no idea and am afraid I've been unable to turn up any answers with my neophyte skills.

And so I appeal to you...

Edit: Here's the error message:

```
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1328:in `stat': Invalid argument @ rb_file
_s_stat - ["may2013"].txt (Errno::EINVAL)
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1328:in `lstat'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1247:in `exist?'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:519:in `block in mv'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1570:in `block in fu_each_src
_dest'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1586:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1568:in `fu_each_src_dest'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:516:in `mv'
        from extracttxt.rb:12:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/find.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in find'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/find.rb:47:in `catch'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/find.rb:47:in `block in find'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/find.rb:42:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/find.rb:42:in `find'
        from extracttxt.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please post the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows that `ret[0]` is the array `[ "may13" ]`, so `ret[0].to_s + ".txt"` evaluates to the string `["may13"].txt`. I'm not sure, but it's possible the behavior of `String#scan` changed in Ruby 1.9 or 2.0, so it returns an array of arrays when captures are present, whereas before it returned an array of strings.

Something like this ought to solve the problem:

```
require 'find'
require 'fileutils'

Find.find("txts") do |path|
  if FileTest.directory?(path)
    next
  end

  if path =~ %r{txts/([^/]+)/}
    FileUtils.cp(path, "#{$1}.txt")
  end
end
```

If you want to match by file extension you could either add it to the Regexp above (e.g. `%r{txts/([^/]+)/.+\.txt$}`) or you could use `Dir[]` (a.k.a. [`Dir.glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob)) e.g.:

```
require 'dir'
require 'fileutils'

Dir['txts/**/*.txt'].each do |path|
  next if FileTest.directory?(path) ||
  next unless path =~ %r{txts/([^/]+)/}

  FileUtils.cp(path, "#{$1}.txt")
end
```

I don't know if there will be any performance difference, but it might be worth trying.

Comment: That's wonderful.  Thank you!  I've changed it to use FileUtils.cp to preserve the contents of the original directories.  However, this unexpectedly results in some serious resource bloat.  Judging by the time it takes to complete the operations, the entire contents of the directories are added to the array.  The output in the txts directory is as intended, though: the new txt files only.  Is there a way we can be more selective when constructing the array?

Comment: More selective in what way? You say "not just the txt files … but the rest of the data as well," but the original script doesn't I differentiate between different kinds of files. Can you explain which files you want copied and which you don't?

Comment: The output achieved by your script is exactly what I want.  Only the txts are copied to parent directory \txts.  However, when I changed FileUtils.mv to FileUtils.cp, processing time dramatically increased, and the directories that take the longest to copy the txt from are those with the largest amounts of incidental additional data.  This leads me to believe that ALL data is being copied, with non-txt data being disposed of when the operation completes, leaving only the desired txts in the \txts directory.  This isn't a deal-breaker, but inefficient and will lead to very long operations...

Comment: I added some code that shows how to selectively copy files with a `.txt` extension. I hope that helps.

Comment: Adding the regex bit to the first one made no performance difference, but the second script (minus `require 'dir'` which is apparently no longer necessary) works flawlessly.  Nearly instantaneous as one would expect.  My HDDs thank you for that, and I again thank you for your time in helping me extract my nfo... err, my txt files :)